# How do you aggregate two columns into arrays in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Say I have a table with 4 columns, `a` of type string, `b` of type integer, `c` of type integer, and `d` of type integer. How would I go ahead and use something like `ARRAY_AGG` on a `STRUCT(b, c)` and `d` separately (in other words, have two separate columns that would be arrays)?

The Query I have so far:

```
SELECT table1.a, table1.x, table2.y
FROM (
  SELECT a, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(b, c)) AS x
  FROM project.table
  GROUP BY a
  ORDER BY a
) AS table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT a, ARRAY_AGG(d) AS y
  FROM project.table
  GROUP BY a, d
  ORDER BY a, d
) table2 ON table1.a = table2.a
GROUP BY table1.a
ORDER BY table1.a;
```

This gives me the error: `SELECT list expression references table1.x which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [1:20]`

But if I try to add `table1.x` to the `GROUP BY` clause at the end, I get a new error: `Grouping by expressions of type ARRAY is not allowed at [14:22]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT a, 
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT b, c FROM t.x GROUP BY b, c
  ) AS x, y
FROM (
  SELECT a,  
    ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(b, c)) AS x, 
    ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT d) AS y
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY a
) t
```

Comment: Works beautifully!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do this in one query?

```
SELECT a, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(b, c)) AS x, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT d) AS y
FROM project.table
GROUP BY a
ORDER BY a;
```

Your version will work without the outer `GROUP BY`.  But it is needlessly compicated.

Comment: This doesn't actually work for me as `x` and `y` end up getting values repeated. Since you cannot just throw a `DISTINCT` to solve this problem, I figured a bit of complexity was needed to try and make two tables with what I wanted, then join them together.

Comment: `array_agg()` supports `distinct`.

Comment: Not when `STRUCT` is used.

Comment: @markzz . . . There is not need on the version with `struct`.  Your query does not have it.  And your question is about how to fix your query to run, not about producing a query to get a particular result.  If you have a question about what logic to use, ask a NEW question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic.